# How would I install files from Github

Tags: github, iexpress

I am making an installer for software, and was wondering how I would have the installer (I'm using IExpress) install files directly from Github

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to install files directly from GitHub using IExpress. However, you can download the files from GitHub on to your computer, then make a installer with IExpress from that.

Comment: While this answers the question, please add more information, for example, how to download from GitHub. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.